# Reading and writing a structure to a pipe in C

Tags: c, struct, fork, pipe

I'm attempting to write a structure consisting of a an array of characters, an integer value, and a pointer to a pipe. The structure represents a node in a singly linked list.

```
//Define a linked-list node object
typedef struct node{
    char word[128];
    int frequency;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;
```

The object of the program is to use a pipe to pass a node from several concurrent child processes to the parent. The pipe structure I've implemented seems to work fine with regular character arrays but won't work if I try to pass the entire node object.

```
    //for each file argument, create a child process
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
        {
            pipe(p[i-1]);
            pid = fork();

            if (pid == 0)
            {
                //child process
                close(p[i-1][0]);
                NODE *tmp;
                NODE *out = freqCheck(argv[i], tmp);
                write(p[i-1][1], out, sizeof(NODE));
                exit(0);
            }
        }
if (pid > 0){
                //parent process
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < argc-1; j++)
                {
                    close(p[j][1]);
                    NODE *tmp;
                    read(p[j][0], tmp, sizeof(NODE));

                    printf("%s\n", tmp->word);
                }


            }
```

When the parent process attempts to read from the pipe and interpret one of the attributes of the structure, I just get null values back.

I'm using an array of 2 element integer arrays to keep track of each child processes' pipe. The printf statement above returns null revery time.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Code for the FrqCheck method:

```
//Method for determining the most occuring word
NODE * freqCheck(char *file, NODE *max)
{
    int i; 
    FILE *f;
    char str[128];

    //Set up head and tail nodes
    NODE *head = NULL;
    NODE *tail = NULL;

    if ((f = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            //sprintf(output, "%s could not be opened.", file);
        }else
        {
            //scan each word of the input file
            while(fscanf(f, "%s ", str) != EOF)
            {
                //if the linked-list has no nodes, create one
                if (head == NULL)
                {
                    NODE *n;
                    n = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
                    strcpy(n->word, str);
                    n->frequency = 1;
                    n->next = NULL;
                    head = n;
                    tail = n;

                }else{  //search the linked list for the found word.

                    NODE *current = head;
                    int found = 0;

                    while((current != NULL) && (found == 0))
                    {
                        //if the word is found increment the frequency
                        if (strcmp(current->word, str) == 0)
                        {
                            current->frequency ++;
                            found = 1;
                        }else
                        {
                            current = current->next;
                        }
                    }

                    //if the word is not found, create a node and add to the liked-list
                    if (found == 0)
                    {
                        NODE *new;
                        new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
                        strcpy(new->word, str);
                        new->frequency = 1;
                        new->next = NULL;
                        tail->next = new;
                        tail = new;
                    }
                }
            }
            //traverse the linked-list and find the word with the maximum frequency
            NODE *tmp = head;
            max = tmp;

            while (tmp != NULL)
            {
                if (tmp->frequency > max->frequency)
                {
                    max = tmp;
                }else
                {
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
            }
            //sprintf(output, "%s %s %d", file, max->word, max->frequency);
        }
    //printf("%s\n", max->word);
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you allocating storage for your `NODE` structures?  Does `freqCheck` allocate storage?  In the parent process, when you call `read()` and then `printf`, you pass in an uninitialized `NODE` pointer, so of course you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes the frequency check constructs the linked list and allocates memory for each node. The method scans the words in the file, and determines which word occurs the most. It returns a node instance.

Comment: @user362685, regardless of what you're doing with `freqCheck`, you still have undefined behavior in the parent process.  You never allocate storage for `NODE *tmp`, but yet you pass it to `read()` and then pass it to `printf`.

Comment: That solved it thanks. Just needed to change it to NODE *tmp = malloc(sizeof(NODE)).

Answer (score 0):

Use buffered read who reads data until whole structure will be readed, because code from parrent can be executed before code from child then you reading data who not exists.

Comment: I have tried adding a wait() call to the parent code, ensuring the parent will execute after the children have finished but I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider 2 things:
1) Execution Coordination:

This is what things like locks, semaphores, events, etc. are for. They enforce an order on the order in which instructions (your lines of code) run. There are versions of these that operate between processes, just like the ones that operate for threads, for precisely this reason. You want a semaphore here- the writer process should post() the sem when a node has been fully transmitted, and the reader process should wait() on the sem before trying to read the next one.

2) Memory:
Processes do NOT share address space. Thus the heaps the reader and writer process have are different chunks of ram. A pipe works fine, but its like a socket- you have all the nastiness of serializing and de-serializing objects into raw streams of bytes. Another thing you could consider, given how small your structs are, is shared memory.

One last thing to consider: Your pointers to the "next" node in your node structure will need to be updated in the child process. Again, it is going to copy these nodes to locations in its own address space, so the 'next' pointers have to be updated accordingly.